# Angularfire2 list() is returning empty the second time

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have two variables courseId and lessonId that are passed to angularfire2's list() method as part of a query. This is used in Next & Previous navigation buttons that walk through a list of items. I am ONLY testing cases where the query will always return an array of two items (no corner cases).

The navigation buttons work fine for say, NEXT NEXT PREV PREV. What consistently fails is sequences like NEXT PREV NEXT* or NEXT NEXT PREV NEXT*. In these cases, the NEXT*, which is where you "go back" to a list item and click NEXT again, crashes.

The reason it crashes is the code below.  According to the .do(console.log), it returns an array of two items like it should on the first time we do NEXT from a list item. But if we come back to that list item and then do that second NEXT* from that same place, the angularfire query returns an empty array every time. Even though the console.log on top confirms that the "lessonId" and "courseId" variables are exactly the same.

So this question is, why does the exact same firebase query return different things? The underlying data never changes. I am learning about Observables and understand that the data "may not be there yet" but it's funny that the first-time NEXT's always have the right data and the second time doesn't.

The observable is subscribed elsewhere, so that is not the issue.

```
console.log("loadNext lesson = ", lessonId, "course = ", courseId);
return this.afdb.list(
  `lessonsPerCourse/${courseId}`,
  {
    query: {
      orderByKey: true,
      startAt: lessonId,
      limitToFirst: 2
    }
  }
)
.do(console.log)
.map(results => results[1].$key)
.switchMap(lessonId => this.afdb.object(`lessons/${lessonId}`))
.map(Lesson.fromJSON);
```

Comment: I worked around this issue by adding .filter(results => results.length == 2) but would still like to know why an empty array was being returned for the exact same query parameters.

Comment: adding .filter(results => results.length == 2) works. Thanks